# Como percorrer cada linha do banco de dados comparar e atualizar uma coluna especifica?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Possuo uma tabela chamada **PRODUTO** e necessito fazer uma comparação entre duas colunas, a coluna **DATA_INICIAL  E DATA_FINAL**, para cada linha percorrida, caso o produto não esteja de acordo deverá inserir o valor `0` na coluna **PROD_ATIVO**.

**Regra:**
Caso a data inicial seja maior que a data atual ou a data final seja menor que a data presente o produto não deverá ser exibido.

**Produto**(Exemplificação)**:**

Nome do produto: Danoninho
 
Data de exibição do produto: 27/03/2017 a 30/03/2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nas tags diz que é mysql portanto você precisa executar um update na tabela de produtos, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
UPDATE produto
SET PROD_ATIVO = 0
WHERE 
DATA_INCIAL > DATE("now")
OR DATA_FINAL < DATE("now");
```

Aqui dizemos: Atualize todos os registros e altere a PROD_ATIVO para 0 onde a data_inicial é maior que a data atual (Função date do mysql) ou a data_final seja menor que a data atual;

Funções de datas do mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

EDIT:
Assumindo que os campos de data estão como timestamp ou date, se estiverem como string aí só convertendo para datas, a função date faz isso também...

Comment: Victor Hartur de Carvalho, aqui não tá funcionando seu código com DATE("now") pq será?

Comment: Desculpe, para mysql a função é `NOW()`. me confundi :)

Comment: A data inicial e final, são da tabela tb_cupons, mas será a tabela produtos que a coluna PROD_ATIVO será atualizada, então como ficaria o UPDATE?

Comment: Voce vai ter que usar alias nas tabelas por exemplo: `update produto p set p.prod_ativo = 0 where (tb_cupons.data_inicial > now() or tb_cupons.data_final < now()) and tb_cupons.id_produto = p.id_produto`

Answer (score 3):

> Se a DATA_FINAL já é menor que a data atual, a DATA_INICIAL nunca que vai ser maior que a data atual.  Portanto basta um update na coluna PROD_ATIVO quando a DATA_FINAL for menor que a data atual.

```
 Update PRODUTO SET PROD_ATIVO='0' where DATA_FINAL < now()
```

> Porém se não houver certeza de que os datas no banco foram inseridos corretamente pode-se fazer assim

```
 Update PRODUTO set PROD_ATIVO='0' where DATA_FINAL < now() or Data_INICIAL > now()
```

Comment: Pode haver problemas de cadastro, então a premissa não é necessariamente válida. Como não foi informado existência de restrições, não se pode supor elas

Comment: Sei como é que é. Funcionário relapso ou controle de qualidade ruim. Mas o rock.ownar é um cara esperto e se achar que deve supor que vc tem razão, vai acrescer no update um OR Data_INICIAL > now(). Portanto ficaria assim Update PRODUTO set PROD_ATIVO='0' where DATA_FINAL < now() or Data_INICIAL > now()

Comment: Tem um jeito bacana de por constraints para garantir esses valores entre as duas colunas no MySql? Faz muito tempo que não mexo nele

Comment: BETWEEN. Sobres constraints de SQL são usadas para especificar as regras para os dados em uma tabela. As seguintes restrições são comumente usados ​​em SQL: NOT NULL - UNIQUE - PRIMARY KEY - FOREIGN KEY - CHECK - DEFAULT - INDEX

Comment: Pois é, queria saber se dá para fazer algo como se faz no  sql server : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13390565

Comment: Ai já não é mais minha área, sorry!

Comment: Na data final preciso que seja comparado com o de outro campos de outra  tabela, exemplo é de uma tabela chamada tb_cupons, como faria?
Update PRODUTO set PROD_ATIVO='0' where TB_CUPONS.DATA_FINAL < now() or TB_CUPONS.Data_INICIAL > now()

Comment: Ai que está o Problema Leo, a coluna prod_ativo está na tabela produtos e comparação deve ser feita na tabela coluna tb_cupons que é a que possui as datas inicial e final

Comment: Pois é, pergunta mal formulada confunde, mas vi no comentário do Victor Hartur de Carvalho  que já resolveu o seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa dar um `UPDATE`. No [Tutorial Points](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm) tem uma página sobre o assunto:

Usando MySQL:

```
UPDATE produto
SET PROD_ATIVO =
    CASE
        WHEN DATA_INICIAL <= now() AND DATA_FINAL > now() THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

#### EDIT

Como mencionado pelo @rock.ownar, o problema é *update* usando múltiplas tabelas.

Você pode conferir a [sintaxe do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) para isso; também tem a alternativa de usar a segunda tabela unicamente na cláusula `where`, como uma *subquery*.

```
UPDATE produto, tb_cupons
SET produto.prod_ativo = 0
WHERE
   produto.produto_id = tb_cupons.produto_id AND
   (
       tb_cupons.data_inicial < now() OR
       tb_cupons.data_final > now()
   )
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, a mensagem é exatamente a consulta que escrevi? Ou você apertou enter antes do tempo? Eu escrevi para SQLite, pois para outro SGBD a função seria outra

Comment: pois é, olha a tag lá, é mysql e sql, da mesma forma "não se pode supor"

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo isso que dá não olhar as tags =D mereci o downvote

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo olha, no contexto original da pergunta estava só com a tag sql... =\

Comment: eu tinha visto isso q tava só sql, kkk

Comment: A data inicial e final, são da tabela tb_cupons, mas será a tabela produtos que a coluna PROD_ATIVO será atualizada, então como ficaria o UPDATE?

Comment: Como você liga a tabela `TB_CUPONS`? Ela tem algum `id_produto` ou coisa similar?

Comment: cupon_id e produto_id